# Read a CSV file, group the data by date and calculate several columns for that date

Tags: powershell, csv

My source CSV file:

```
"Name","timestamp","CPU|Demand (%)","CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)","CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)"
"BDC00-Management","Mar 2, 2017 12:01:22 AM","","30.68",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 2, 2017 12:10:00 AM","34.19","",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 2, 2017 12:16:22 AM","","30.68",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 2, 2017 12:20:00 AM","29.59","",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 3, 2017 6:55:00 AM","28.76","",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 3, 2017 7:00:00 AM","33.44","",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 3, 2017 7:01:22 AM","","30.98",""
"BDC00-Management","Apr 1, 2017 7:01:22 PM","","","37.98"
"BDC00-Management","Apr 1, 2017 7:21:22 PM","","","37.99"
"BDC01-Horizon","Apr 2, 2017 2:56:22 AM","","","16.8"
"BDC01-Horizon","Apr 2, 2017 3:06:22 AM","","","16.78"
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 30, 2017 9:31:22 AM","","18.49",""
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 30, 2017 9:40:00 AM","18.32","",""
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 30, 2017 9:41:22 AM","","18.49",""
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 31, 2017 1:30:00 PM","18.48","",""
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 31, 2017 1:36:22 PM","","18.58",""
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 1, 2017 9:51:22 PM","","","18.67"
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 1, 2017 10:11:22 PM","","","18.68"
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 2, 2017 4:16:22 AM","","","18.69"
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 2, 2017 4:46:22 AM","","","18.7"
```

I need to `Export-Csv` with one line output with the higher number per day for each "Name". Example:

```
"Name","timestamp","CPU|Demand (%)","CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)","CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)"
"BDC00-Management","Mar 2, 2017","34.19","30.68",""
"BDC00-Management","Mar 3, 2017","33.44","30.98",""
"BDC00-Management","Apr 1, 2017","","","37.99"
"BDC01-Horizon","Apr 2, 2017","","","16.8"
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 30, 2017","18.32","18.49",""
"BDC01-Linux","Mar 31, 2017","18.48","18.58",""
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 1, 2017","","","18.68"
"BDC01-Linux","Apr 2, 2017","","","18.7"
```

The source file has more than 750,000 lines and I need to reduce the size for automated graphic report in SharePoint. It's to big and I don't need info for each 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `Group-Object` to group the entries by name and date and generate a new object where you've calculated the max-values. Be aware that this requires the whole CSV to be read into memory. It will be slow and use much memory for that many rows.

Comments are in the code. Try:

```
#Read csv-input
Import-Csv -Path "c:\old.csv" |
#Group entries by server and date
Group-Object Name, { ($_.timestamp -as [datetime]).Date } |
ForEach-Object {
    #Create new object per server per day with max-values
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property ([ordered]@{
        Name = $_.Group[0].Name
        timestamp = ($_.Group[0].timestamp -as [datetime]).ToString("MMM d, yyyy")
        "CPU|Demand (%)" = $_.Group | Measure-Object -Property "CPU|Demand (%)" -Maximum | ForEach-Object { if($_.Maximum -gt 0) { $_.Maximum } }
        "CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)" = $_.Group | Measure-Object -Property "CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)" -Maximum | ForEach-Object { if($_.Maximum -gt 0) { $_.Maximum } }
        "CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)" = $_.Group | Measure-Object -Property "CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)" -Maximum | ForEach-Object { if($_.Maximum -gt 0) { $_.Maximum } }
    })
} | Export-Csv -Path "c:\new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Name","timestamp","CPU|Demand (%)","CPU|Demand (%) (Trend)","CPU|Demand (%) (30 days forecast)"
"BDC00-Management","mar 2, 2017","34,19","30,68",""
"BDC00-Management","mar 3, 2017","33,44","30,98",""
"BDC00-Management","apr 1, 2017","","","37,99"
"BDC01-Horizon","apr 2, 2017","","","16,8"
"BDC01-Linux","mar 30, 2017","18,32","18,49",""
"BDC01-Linux","mar 31, 2017","18,48","18,58",""
"BDC01-Linux","apr 1, 2017","","","18,68"
"BDC01-Linux","apr 2, 2017","","","18,7"
```

Comment: Wow, ..  works perfectly
thank you sooooo much  :-)

can you recommend me a eBook for stuff like this for PowerShell  ?

Have a beautifull day  :-)

Comment: No, sorry. The best way is to learn how powershell works then you'll figure it out yourself. Check out https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/getting-started-with-microsoft-powershell-8276 and https://www.youtube.com/user/powershelldon/featured .  Also, remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem to close the question. :-)